# Save file to server instead of my computer on PHP

Tags: php, file, download

I have a url that downloads a .csv file to my computer like this
http://oi62.tinypic.com/2nh0zzt.jpg

The url is

```
api.infortisa.com/api/Tarifa/GetFile?user=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But what I want is to download that file in a folder of the server, or at least open it's content so I can save it where i want.
(upload that file via FTP every time is a pain)

I can't access the direct url of the file, just what the api gives me, and that is just a direct download.

I tried curl and file_get_contents, but nothing seems to work.

How can I download that file in the server instead of my computer?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you replicate EVERYTHING that your browser is doing, including cookies/http headers? Just because you've copied the url doesn't mean much. there's much more to http requests than just the url.

Comment: The url just leads me to a direct download, no cookies nor headers

Comment: Found the solution, for anyone with the same question:

file_put_contents("Csvfile.csv", file_get_contents("url of the file you want to download to the server"));

It was very simple.